# Filter changes from TFS Build Agent

Tags: build-process, build-automation, tfsbuild

I have a build process that records some information about the build and then checks that information back into TFS.  This check back in is causing another build to be triggered.

When my build was using CruiseControl, I could filter out changes that a user made. My question is how can I filter changes made from the build agent?

Answer (score 1):

If it's firing a new build because you have a CI build setup, you can set the check-in comment to include the text *****NO_CI***** which will suppress any CI builds.

Answer (score 1):

There are different build trigger types that can be triggered by a checkin: CI, Rolling, or Gated Checkin.

If you're dealing with a CI or Rolling build definition, what Dylan said about `***NO_CI***` would work. If you're dealing with a Gated Checkin build definition, set the right workspace parameters and grant permission to bypass gated checkin for the build service account as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049739/can-i-bypass-gated-check-in-build-after-checking-a-file-in-during-a-separate-bui/8051565#8051565).

The most important thing is, if these files that you check in TFS again during your build don't need to be built, you should cloak the build definition's folder mappings for these files so you would not need to do any extra thing to suppress triggering a build.